# django-tasty-pie turn char field to JSON

Tags: django, api, rest, tastypie

I'm using JSONfield to store some JSON formated data in one field.  But when I go to my API which build with help of tasty-pie it returns that jason as a string not a nested JSON as I expected.

## models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    body = JSONField(max_length=1024)
```

## api.py

```
 class ItemResource(ModelResource):
    authorization = Authorization()
    authentication = SessionAuthentication()
    list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']

    class Meta:
        queryset = Item.objects.filter()

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        return super(ItemResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(user=request.user)

    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(user=request.user)

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        # how to modify bundle['body'] here ? so it work
        return bundle
```

Obviously JSONfield is sublased from django's standart TextField. So when I retrieve API i receive follow:

```
 {
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 1
    },
    "objects": [
       {
        "body": "{u'valid': u'json'}",
        "id": 1,
        "resource_uri": "/api/v1/testitem/1/"
        }
    ]
  }
```

and this is what I want to receive:

```
 {
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 1
    },
    "objects": [
       {
        "body": {
             "valid': "json"
           },
        "id": 1,
        "resource_uri": "/api/v1/testitem/1/"
        }
    ]
  }
```

Notice difference in `body` field?

And if I do:

```
    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle['body'] = json.loads(bundle['body'])
        return bundle
```

I receive this exception:

```
{"error_message": "Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/Users/polinom/Envs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 202, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/polinom/Envs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 439, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/polinom/Envs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 471, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/polinom/Envs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1270, in get_list\n    bundles.append(self.full_dehydrate(bundle))\n\n  File \"/Users/polinom/Envs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 845, in full_dehydrate\n    bundle = self.dehydrate(bundle)\n\n  File \"/Users/polinom/workspace/microjob/applications/examinations/api.py\", line 24, in dehydrate\n    bundle.data['body'] = json.loads(bundle.data['body'])\n\n  File \"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py\", line 326, in loads\n    return _default_decoder.decode(s)\n\n  File \"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py\", line 360, in decode\n    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())\n\n  File \"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py\", line 376, in raw_decode\n    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)\n\nValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)\n"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After creating the bundle(s), the [response is created](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1174) by [serializing the content](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L360). For json format and default Serializer, it first [convert any complex type to python basic types](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/serializers.py#L198) and then [dumps it in a string representation](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/serializers.py#L341).

As you can see, in the case of a original string, it justs convert it to unicode. You need to convert it to a `dict` before serialize the resource. So, in the `dehydrate` method you can do:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle['body'] = json.loads(bundle.data['body'])
    return bundle
```

Since you are only modifying one element, you can also can do:

```
def dehydrate_body(self, bundle):
    return json.loads(bundle.data['body'])
```

---

The JSONField stores a python dict representation, not a JSON representation. So, my first attempt is incorrect. You can `return eval(bundle.data['body'])`. IMO the use of `eval` here is safe because the JSONField ensures that the content is a statement that can be directly translated to a json representation.

Comment: And uf I do so, than i receive exaction.

Comment: thanks but I needed to do eval(bundle.data['body']) which is not secure right?

Comment: @Pol: yes, sorry about that. I didn't test the code. eval is not secure in some cases. But IMO is safe because the `JSONField` ensures a valid json in the content.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to leave like that for now. However, later I will write custom api.field for model JSONfield.

Comment: you can use literal_eval instead eval; as per Python docs : "See ast.literal_eval() for a function that can safely evaluate strings with expressions containing only literals."